# Search Query not works Properly : Php Like Query

Tags: php, mysql

```
 <?php
    include"configration.php";  
?>

 <?php
    $query = $_GET['query'];
    $min_length = 1;
    //echo $query;exit();
    if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) { // if query length is more or equal minimum length then
        //echo "success";exit();
        $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
        $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM table2
                WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' order by date DESC";
        $raw_results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
        if (mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) { // if one or more rows are returned do following
            while ($res = mysqli_fetch_array($raw_results)) { ?>
    
              <?php echo $res['title'] ?> // Place where result comes ..
    
            <?php }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

This is code works fine but search in this way

For Example Title is: `you are vary nice boy but lazy`

When I search by:

> You are vary ............. result shows ..
>
> vary nice boy ............. result shows ..
>
> vary lazy, or boy lazy or vary lazy .. result not shows ..

Plz some one help me in this and how to show searched query in title ..

```
   <title> Searched Query ...</title>
```

Comment: beware : you are mixing `mysqli_x` and `mysql_x` functions. you have to use `mysqli_error()`. Also, you should have a look at **prepared statements** which are safer than escaping strings with `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: Use prepared statements, not escape strings.  There's also probably no reason to use htmlspecialchars here, that should be used on output, not input..

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the question indicated. OP wants to know how to match a specific string pattern using "LIKE".

Comment: I for one have no idea what you're asking here.

Comment: I've re-opened, there are multiple issues at hand here.

Comment: I see what he is trying to do... but its really a complex issue to cover in a simple example based on his code :(

Comment: @Devon actually, I was about to include 2 more duplicates for this, as their query failed, outright. I might reclose.

Comment: yeah, that's fine but i don't think the dup I chose represented the main issue of the question

Comment: The way to do this is to `explode` the string by a regex (word boundaries), and then construct a series of `LIKE` clauses for each separate word.  I've done it before, but @FunkFortyNiner is right - a big ask for what has been provided as far as code goes.

Comment: @Devon it's part of it. If the query failed, the `mysql_error()` would not show them real reason why it failed, hence the "mixing of apis" fits the bill for me.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner but his query really isn't failing ... its just not returning the rows he wants when searching by two split words instead of a string of matching words. Bit of a difference there ;)

Comment: Edit ping: @IncredibleHat --- (original) Meh, I'll just vote to close this as a generic and won't be bothered.

Comment: @IncredibleHat Too broad and unclear, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

When you search `title LIKE "%vary lazy%"`, you will get records that contain the string "vary lazy" preceeded and followed by any other or no character sequences. If you want to match strings that contain the words - I should better say, the character sequences -  "vary" and "lazy" in *that specific order* you should use:

```
title LIKE "%vary%lazy%"
```

However, this will also match "varylazy", "varying lazytown characters".

Assuming you generally intend to use queries as you mentioned, i.e. each word is separated by a space character and you want to see if those words appear in a text in specifically that order, you could write something like this:

```
$query = $_GET["query"];
$query = '%'.str_replace(' ', '%', $query).'%';

//... MySQL stuff
```

Please be aware that the code above is very specific to your needs. I wouldn't use it as a general purpose approach for processing query strings, e.g. having multiple spaces between words would result in multiple consequent `%` in your SQL query - I'm not even sure if that is allowed. However, under the constraints described, this code should work just fine.

Comment: WHERE title LIKE '%".$query."%' what to change .. means how to write according to the way you said..

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE '%boy lazy%'` will show the Of the cases where anything can be before `boy lazy` and anything can be after `boy lazy`, but `boy lazy` will be together.

In your case, one approach can be, you can explode your `$query`, and then use multiple `LIKE` queries to create sql query. Example:

```
<?php
//$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","your user","your pass","db");
$query = $_GET['query'];
$min_length = 1;
//echo $query;exit();
if (strlen($query) >= $min_length) { // if query length is more or equal minimum length then
    //echo "success";exit();
    $query = htmlspecialchars($query);
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $query);
    $searchKeys = explode(' ',$query);
    $sql = "SELECT * from table2 where title ";
    foreach ($searchKeys as $key) {
      $sql.= "LIKE '%".$key."%' AND title ";
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, -10);
    //$sql.="ORDER BY date DESC;";
    $raw_results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if (mysqli_num_rows($raw_results) > 0) { // if one or more rows are returned do following
        while ($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($raw_results)) {
            echo $res['title']."\n";
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have complete code ? .. i tried but result not shows .. if you have time then Plz give the complete code... lot of errors comes when i write code in this format .

Comment: @Sahil I have editted the my answer above with the full code. If u still have problems you may comment.

Comment: i tried this code but where to show results and how... i tried that code you write but no result shows  .. i have edited the question code that how i display results..  there are 9 fields all other fields comes according to searched title ..  i display results like this <?php echo $res['title'] ?> and other field also like this ..